# Chrome NOT performing a preflight request

Tags: google-chrome, cors

I've worked with some previous APIs in AngularJS, however there has always been a preflight using the `OPTIONS` method. Now I am building a new API from scratch and for some reason, AngularJS does NOT send a preflight request.

From what I have experienced AngularJS always sends a preflight when working with `CORS`, but not in my case. So question is really, what triggers a preflight in AngularJS if its not request to a domain which is not the same as the one AngularJS is being hosted on?

**The example I have is quite easy and looks like this:**

```
$scope.submit = function () {
  $http.post('https://slimapi.devz/')
    .then(function successCallback(response){
      alert(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
}
```

The requesting URL is `https://slimfrontend.devz/`.

Chrome gets triggered by the response headers in the `XHR` with the `POST` method, and will not display the result, however, the result is being fetched (as seen in timeline). But again, there is no sign of `OPTIONS` preflight.

Here is a picture of what my request looks like, and as you can see by the arrow. Chrome does detect the bad match of the origin.

[image: timeline view]

Comment: Angular is not responsible of sending preflight checks, that's the browser.

Comment: @MinusFour, Oh... that this was integrated in AngularJS. Well home come Chrome doesnt send preflight?

Comment: How do you know it's not sending one? Where's the data being sent?

Comment: @charlietfl Preflights show up in the timeline, or atleast it does for other websites.

Comment: Try sending some data...I bet things change

Comment: @charlietfl, Yeah, I just thought preflights usually was sent with every request, but apparently not :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MDN has a good description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests):

> In particular, a request is preflighted if any of the following conditions is true:

(I paraphrase the rest below)

- If the request uses any of the following methods (such as PUT)
- If particular HTTP headers are set by the JS
- If the `Content-Type` is not a valid value for the `enctype` attribute of an HTML `<form>`

---

IIRC, Angular defaults to sending `application/json` payloads (which trigger the final condition above).

Your example is of a POST request where you aren't POSTing any data (which is odd) so there is no Content-Type.

Comment: This really explains a lot in a few words... I have never really been sure about the preflight conditions. Thanks! :)

Comment: Does it skip the pre-flight if the request is on the same origin?

Comment: @VictorioBerra — The first sentence of the page says: "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a **different origin**." So yes, it doesn't make a preflight for same origin requests.